# How do you play a clip backwards in Sony Vegas?

Tags: editing, vegas-pro

While editing some vocals the other day, I accidentally hit a key in Vegas and the scrub head started going backwards, playing my audio in reverse. I wasn't trying to do this at the time and got it playing normal again. Today I was thinking that this could be useful when trying to find a point where the vocalist takes a breath. Rather than guess, split the clip and play from a few seconds earlier to hear if it is gone, then repeat the process, you could just set the play head past the breath, play it backwards and find the exact point that they start their breath.

Does anyone know the key you hit to play the scrub head backwards in Sony Vegas?

(This is not flipping the clip to play in reverse using "Right-click/Reverse", I don't need that, I just need the play head to play in reverse temporarily, like scrubbing it backwards)

Comment: I found something that might help clarify what I am looking for: If you drag the "Rate" arrows (bottom left corner of the timeline) to the left a little, it will read "-1.02" or whatever; I am looking for this effect with just a keystroke. thank you!

Comment: OK, one more example: Click the "Rate" arrows and then jog your mouse wheel up until it reads "-1.00" this is the EXACT effect I need, but the problem is this, when I move the mouse back into the timeline, it starts playing forward again... I need it to play like that until I specifically tell it to play forward again.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but is it possible to make a community wiki where it is explained for each major audio and video editor how to reverse footage?

Comment: That would be nice, but I personally have no experience with that sort of thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

You can press the "J" key to play in reverse. Each time you hit the "J" it will jump a full speed up to x4. If you want to jump by speeds of .25x, hold the "K" button and hit "J". While it is play backwards, hitting the spacebar will jump you back to where you started playing, and hitting "K" will stop you where you are.

To adjust playback speeds going forward, you can use the "L" key in the same manor.

To find the exact point where a breath is taken, you place the play head about where the breath starts, then hit "J", it will play backwards for a bit. Hit the spacebar and adjust the playback spot by hitting the left or right arrow, then hit "J" again. Once you are exactly where you want to cut the clip, hit "S" and you will split the clip right there.

(The arrows will jump one "frame" according to the frame rate of your project, even if it is an audio project. If it is set to 24 fps, it will jump 1/24th of a second forward or backward)